# How do I get C# [HTTPPOST] data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I did about 20 minutes of browsing and cant figure this out. 
**How do I fetch the data that is POSTED to my URL**?

Do I need the FormCollection argument?

Is there a good alternative to the print_r() or vardump() function PHP uses? Or do I just rely on breakpoints in the debugger?

```
    [IsLogged]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveRecord(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var disease = Convert.ToString(formCollection.GetValue("disease"));
        var link = Convert.ToString(formCollection.GetValue("link"));

        disease = Server.HtmlEncode(disease);
        link = Server.HtmlEncode(link);

        string[] output = new string[] { disease, link };
        return Json(output);

    }
```

-- EDIT: Client Side Code --

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SaveRecord", "Dashboard")">

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Disease</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea name="disease" placeholder="Insert the details of your disease."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Remedy Link</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Provide the link to your remedy." />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Record" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Cliff Notes: I'm only a few days new to MVC3 so be nice :) This language is quite a bit more advanced than what I'm used to but it's pretty sweet.

**Here is my final solution!**

### All I wanted was the POST without all this model stuff, Im doing manual SQL stuff, not Entity.

```
    [IsLogged]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveRecord()
    {

        var disease = Convert.ToString(Request["disease"]);
        var link = Convert.ToString(Request["link"]);

        disease = Server.HtmlEncode(disease);
        link = Server.HtmlEncode(link);

        string[] output = new string[] { disease, link };
        return Json(output);

    }
```

Comment: can u show the client side code?

Comment: Also note that the Json method can serialize strongly typed objects as well and even IEnumerable<T>. So you don't have to use a string[], you can use an actual class there as well.

Comment: This is what I wanted: Request["link"] -- Updating my post for final example.

Comment: _All I wanted was the POST without all this model stuff, Im doing manual SQL stuff, not Entity._ Then why are you bothering to use MVC? You can use models with out EF. ASP.NET MVC doesn't care what your persistence layer is.

Comment: Well I assumed he was using EF for those models {get;set;} as I read about in a long tutorial. Sorry Im not very fluent with this setup yet, I dont yet follow the strictly typed views. My logic is: Models handle the business logic, I can do SQL work in there.. From my controller, I apply "using Mynamespace.Models.MyModel" and I can instantiate the Model.DoSomething() from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently asked this myself.

What you need is `Request.Form` but it will only show variable names, not values since it's NameValueCollection. In order for you to make it show on Json output you will need to convert it Dictionary.

### My code

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializes object to JSON format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">Object</param>
/// <returns>JSON string</returns>
public static string SerializeObject(Object input, bool debug = true)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, MaxDepth = 2 });
    if (debug)
    {
        return "<pre>" + json + "</pre>"; // In order to preview in browser
    }

    return json;
}

/// <summary>
/// Serializes Request.Form (NameValueCollection) to JSON format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">NameValueCollection</param>
/// <returns>JSON string</returns>
public static string SerializePostRequest(NameValueCollection post)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string key in post.Keys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, post[key]);
    }

    return SerializeObject(dict);
}
```

### Usage

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveRecord(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    // Same as print_r($_POST) in php
    return Content(SerializePostRequest(Request.Form));
}
```

Comment: thanks this helped me find what i wanted, i posted it at the top

Answer (score 3):

Use a strongly typed View with a Model:

```
@model YourModel
```

and add an argument for your Model in your action:

```
public JsonResult SaveRecord(YourModel model)
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however Im not using Entity framework at all and I know that guys tutorial uses it. Im not very advanced yet.

Comment: @JREAM using models in an MVC project is **nothing** to do with Entity Framework. Entity Framework is a data layer for mapping objects to database tables. 

MVC models are objects which map to your client-side HTML data (form data).

Answer (score 2):

jrummell is right. You'll want to create a strongly typed view and a model containing property names that match the name attribute of your form inputs with the following definition:

```
public class YourModel
{
   public string Disease { get; set; }

   public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Once you do this, the model binder with create your strongly typed model based on the results provided by the value providers. Here's [a link with more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

Values providers are just wrappers around objects like the RouteValueDictionary, Request.Form, Request.Files, Request.QueryString, etc. The MVC guys neatly abstracted this stuff away so you don't have to deal with it directly. The model binder receives these values and uses it to populate your model.